# Adding OCR library causes error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, ocr

I have some trouble adding an OCR library to an existing Eclipse project. I already tried to add the Tess4J and J4L java wrappers for Tesseract-OCR and the Asprise jar-file without success. The problem is each time i want to run an application, eclipse prints **javaw usage message** (same issue described here: [Trouble compiling any java code in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862037/trouble-compiling-any-java-code-in-eclipse)). I can run application by removing the libraries from the build path, so I'm pretty sure my java-setup is correct. In addition I already tried restarting windows, reinstalling java and eclipse with no success either. I hope somebody has a solution or at least some advice for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. There is some unclear incompatibility between J4L (or Asprise) OCR and H2 Database Engine. Removing H2's .jar file from the build path resolved the issue.